# Google Drive SDK Revision History Download Buggy

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there a bug in the Google Drive Revision history download?  When I retrieve a list of revision histories and try to download via the download URL, the request often hangs and timeouts.

Some files work like a charm and others just hang except for the latest revision.

Also if you go into drive.google.com and try to download that same revision through the Google Drive interface I get the same problem. Chrome says "starting download" but never downloads anything.

Does this do with a revision not being pinned and thus being purged? If this is the case does this mean you can only retrieve pinned revisions?  All the revisions seem to not be pinned.

Answer (score 0):

If you retry the download, does it work?

Many of the Drive API calls fail with various 5xx errors, which generally succeed after an exponential backoff and retry.

Comment: No it just fails.  Just tried getting a version from yesterday and it fails.  Same thing happens in the Google Drive interface, download of the revision just hangs.

If I have to pin revisions that is fine it is just strange that Google would list revisions in both the SDK and Google Drive interface and then you can't download them.

Comment: When I tried the download in Chrome in the Google Drive interface, it looks like the download starts and never finishes.  Only 159 bytes out of 170 bytes of the revision are downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

From talking with a Google Developer, this Looks like this was a bug on the Google side of things.  Should be fixed this week.